# XMLHttpRequest readyState stuck at 1 and never reach 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

This is my code. i don't know what's wrong with my code but the readyState always return 1 and the status always return 0. can anyone please help me?

```
function Registered() {
    console.log("masuk function");
    var xmlhttp;
    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/webchatBack/webchat/getQueueCount?t="+randomNum;
    var xmlDoc;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        console.log("masuk xml");
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject){// code for IE6, IE5
        console.log("masuk active");
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("masuk function lagi");
        console.log(xmlhttp.readyState);
        console.log(xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log("masuk if");
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            var result = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Result");
            result = result[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            console.log(result);
            document.getElementById("agentLoginData").innerHTML = result;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"");
    xmlhttp.send('');
}
```

Comment: XMLHttp request should be in the same domain.

Comment: how can i know if my XHR is in the same domain or not?